# Does jQuery redraw the page on .css() calls if no changes are made?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So in terms of speed of a page, we all know that manipulating the page forces it to redraw and that this is taxing on the browser. So if I have a div with this css applied:

```
div{
    position: static;
}
```

and change it to

```
div{
    position: fixed;
}
```

it's going to refresh the page and change the layout. My question is though, if the div already has fixed applied to it and I execute

```
jQuery('div').css('position', 'fixed');
```

Is it going to cause a redraw, or will it just see that it's set already and go along its merry way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This behavior is not jQuery's choice. The library only manipulates the DOM and relies on the browser to update its window when it sees fit.

Comment: I guess I should ammend the question a bit then, will jQuery apply 'fixed' to it, or see that it is fixed already and do nothing?

Comment: jQuery (as of version 1.7.1) does not check if the style is already applied to the element (probably for performance reasons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `.css()` call will alter the DOM element but it's up to the browser to redraw anything.

Here is quite an interesting write-up from Mozilla about redraws: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html#reflow-reason (notice I deep-linked to the "Reflow Reason" section)

**UPDATE**

In your situation where you set the `position : fixed` for an element that already has `position : fixed` there won't be much overhead due to redrawing. Elements with `position : fixed` or `position : absolute` are removed from the normal flow of the DOM and when they are manipulated it doesn't trigger a whole redraw of the DOM. Instead only the element itself and any overlapping elements are redrawn.

On a side-note, this is important if you are animating anything because animations cause lots of redraws and if you don't set `position : fixed` or `position : absolute` then the whole DOM will be redrawn for each step in the animation. Also any elements with `display : table` will potentially take up to three times as long to redraw due to the recursive nature of the redraw for this element (**stop using tables for layout :)**).

Comment: Good job calling out that it's going to be out of the flow.

Comment: I guess the question is more focused around the idea of "Will jQuery check to see if a style is already applied before applying it again?" Regardless of fixed, absolute, etc., will it just see that X style is applied and do nothing, or will it blindly apply the CSS, potentially doing a redraw if the browser sees fit?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't, but then that's a browser behavior, not a jQuery behavior. I don't see why it would redraw anything if the rendering engine doesn't receive a property update.

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` or `DOMElement.style` add inline style to an element, in your case style of the `div` was not inline and after `jQuery('div').css('position', 'fixed');` command DOM tree will change. Browser will absolutely redraw (render) the page again.

I'm not sure but I guess even if same `style` was in DOM tree and you reassigning the `style` browser will render the page again.

Answer (score 0):

So, to be safe, don't make the property change unless it's necessary?

```
if(jQuery('div').css('position') != 'fixed')
    jQuery('div').css('position', 'fixed');
```